# Present Modal View in Detail View in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to make a behavior like contacts app in iPad with landscape mode.

I'm expecting that a Modal shows in a Detail view when I click upper **right add button**.

but now if I click upper right **add button**, the **Modal shows in all screen**.

what method should I use? showDetailViewController? or presentViewController? I don’t know how to show Modal in only Detail View.

Comment: yeah, same here, did you found answer?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to set detail view controller's property `definesPresentationContext = true`. So now it defines [presentation context](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621456-definespresentationcontext). By default view controllers doesn't pay attention to the current context when they are presented therefore you must do `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext`

That's how complete method looks like

```
func adaptivePresentViewController(viewController: UIViewController) {
  let detailVC = splitViewController!.viewControllers[1]
  detailVC.definesPresentationContext = true
  viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
  detailVC.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```